# Error loading C:\windows\system32\sshnas21.dll

Tags: windows-vista

I'm using vista ultimate 32 bit. When i login to my machine.

Error loading C:\windows\system32\sshnas21.dll

The specified module could not be found.

I don't know how to resole this. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

[A Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=sshnas21.dll) shows that `sshnas21.dll` is malicious. I don't know how to resolve it, but you should probably scan for viruses or something.